# Plotting Inequalities in Sympy Python

Tags: python, math, graph, sympy, inequality

I have this code that shows the area that satisfies inequalities but I need the lines (x=3 and y=x) to be shown on the graph as well.

Any help is appreciated!

My Code:

```
from sympy import *
x, y, z, t = symbols('x y z t')
p1 = plot_implicit(And( x > 3, y > x))
```

Comment: What lines? The two lines given by their respective equations `x == 3` and `y == x`?

Comment: Take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72092145/2329968

Comment: @Stef Yes x = 3 and y=x, sorry should have clarified in the question!

Comment: `plot_implicit(And(x > 3, y > x), markers=[{'args': [[3, 3], [-5, 5]], 'color': 'r', 'ls': '--'}, {'args': [[-5, 5], [-5, 5]], 'color': 'r', 'ls': '--'}])`